# Singleton pattern doesn't supported by ClientEncryption |Java 11.0.10+9 Red Hat, Getting double free detected in tcache Intermittently

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am running in a situation wherein after 12-13 hr of up-time, My Azure pod running JVM crash with the below error

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3e214fbd21, pid=1, tid=91
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.10+9) (build 11.0.10+9-LTS)
> Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.10+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
> Problematic frame:
> C  [libc.so.6+0x21d21]  abort+0x203
>
> Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or dumping to /home/jboss/core.1)
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
> /home/jboss/hs_err_pid1.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%208&component=java-11-openjdk
> The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

> JRE build version is 11.0.10+9-LTS(OpenJDK Runtime Environment RedHat)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.10+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, Linux-amd64
> **I am using spring boot with spring data JPA,**

I have observed from logs whenever my application opens a connection to mongo its lands on this JVM crach.

```
2021-05-05 07:36:29.512 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] c.xxx.xx.xx.SectionHandlerService        [db340496-d1fb-43f0-92c9-f7114194dfbf] : questionnaire  extracted with Id :: 4308655
2021-05-05 07:36:29.512 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] com.xxx.utils.MapperUtil               [db340496-d1fb-43f0-92c9-f7114194dfbf] : mapToModel Started
2021-05-05 07:36:29.512 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] com.xxx.utils.MapperUtil               [db340496-d1fb-43f0-92c9-f7114194dfbf] : Converting com.xxx.xxx.entity.Section To com.xxx.xxxxx.SectionModel class using mapToModel
2021-05-05 07:36:29.623  INFO 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            [db340496-d1fb-43f0-92c9-f7114194dfbf] : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:266, serverValue:267840}] to xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:27017
```

After my last statement i.e Opened connection my application lands to JVM crash.

*Now I need to understand whether something is wrong with the java mongo driver I am using as, As soon as the application opens the mongo connection the pod gets restarted with the above JVM error.*

It's difficult to Produce this issue.
If our application run with full load its working fine and if we run the application after 12 hr of ideal time we are land to this JVM crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for it.
It's not a problem with JVM, Its problem with `mongo-driver-sync` Library.
The singleton object creation of clientEncryption object causes JVM to Crash after a certain amount of ideal time.

In our case, once we start the application and have some encryption it's working fine but after a certain amount of time if we kept the application ideal and then try to have the encryption using the same singleton instance, then JVM land to crash.

With the new object for clientEncryption, it's working fine But this solution comes with a more serious problem in terms of system slowness while encrypting and decrypting the data.

Raised the ticket to Mongo [Ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-4150)
Lets see what solution they will have